# Como reusar codigo XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicacion en WPF la cual consta de varias paginas. Muchas de las cuales tienen cosas en comun, como por ejemplo una misma barra de menu, una barra de titulo debajo de la barra de menu y un scrool viewer el cual contiene todos los demas controles que diferencia una pagina de otra.

Lo que he hecho hasta el momento es Crearme una pagina con la barra de menu y un frame en el cual muestro las otras paginas, es decir la informacion diferente de las otras paginas.

Quiciera saber cual es la mejor forma de hacer estas cosas y de no repetir codigo. Saludos y disculpen mis modestos conocimientos.

Comment: Te sugiero que agregues el código de lo que haz hecho hasta ahora para poder ayudarte con una mejor idea, y darte una opinión de cómo puedes optimizar tu código

Answer (score 2):

Yo hago eso creando UserControls, y los guardo en la carpeta Views, ojo, puede llevar binding a un ViewModel como también puede no llevarlo, es tu diseño.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.FantasticMenu"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"     
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
           d:DesignHeight="32" d:DesignWidth="600">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:MyOptionalMenuViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}">
        <!-- diseño del control -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Luego en la página donde quiera usarlo agrego el namespace:

```
xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
```

y posteriormente agrego el control que hice dentro de un Grid u otro contenedor..

```
<Grid>
 <view:FantasticMenu/>
</Grid>
```

Eso es todo, solo ten en cuenta que cada vez que lo pongas en XAML estarás creando una nueva instancia del control, no será el mismo.

**EDIT:**

**Para complementar la respuesta:**

En ultimo ejemplo XAML déjalo así:

```
<Grid>
        <view:FantasticMenu x:Name="myMenu"/>
</Grid>
```

En el XAML del userControl agregas el grid que mencionas:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid_controls" Margin="0"/>
```

Luego en el codigo C# del UserControl haz un método así:

```
public void AgregarControl(UIElement control)
{
    grid_controls.Children.Add(control);
}
```

y cuando quieras agregar algo al grid que está en el UserControl lo puedes hacer desde donde tengas acceso a él de este modo, por ejemplo, agregando un datepicker al grid que está dentro del usercontrol..

```
private void AgregarControlAlUserControl()
{
    DatePicker dp = new DatePicker();
    myMenu.AgregarControl(dp);
}
```

Con eso queda más claro supongo.

Comment: OK. Gracias por tu respuesta. Y por ejemplo si mi user control tiene un grid(por ejemplo) y luego desde la pagina donde lo usare quiciera agregar nuevos controles a ese grid. Por ejemplo algo como: <views:FantasticMenu><GridDeFantasticMenu>Nuevos controles</GridDeFantasticMenu></views:FantasticMenu>

Comment: Solo hazle un método público en el código y luego llamas al usercontrol por su nombre (en la respuesta no le puse nombre al control en el ultimo trozo de codigo xaml pero tu ponle uno) y luego con el nombre llamas a su método.. mira los usercontrols como cualquier control wpf normal.

Si tienes un grid le haces un método public void AgregarControl(UIElement control) y en el método llamas al grid y le agregas lo que llegue por parámetro, un DatePicker, un Label, o lo que sea, puedes agregar nuevos usercontrols incluso dentro.. asi:  miGrid.Childrens.Add(control);

No es complejo :)